# Flex RemoteObject .Net Session Mixups

Tags: .net, apache-flex, session, weborb, remoteobject

Okay, this one is REALLY weird. I'm using .net for my backend and Flex for my front end. I'm also using WebOrb.Net to manage my RemoteObject calls.

When the user first opens up my Flex app I make a call back to .Net and save a few settings in a session variable so that all subsequent requests to .Net can just pull these values out of the session and thus I don't have to pass them every time. Now on the .Net side I have a model that I stored these values in and then I have the model save itself to the session. So any .Net class can get a static reference to the model whenever it needs it and that reference will load the values out of the session.

If I just have one user using the app everything works great! If I have two users using the app simultaneously we start to run into issues. User A will start to pick up the settings for User B. How is this even possible. I thought sessions were supposed to unique to the user.

If anyone could offer some assistance on this one that would be AMAZING!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem might be in the way you are dealing with the static object. Because it is static, there is only one static object that is shared across all sessions. You might be in inadvertently overwriting  its values within each session when you set the variables. Can you post some code that we can further analyze how you are setting there variables?

Comment: This was exactly it. I updated the object to be non-static and that fixed up everything. THANKS!